# Application wide constants in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have an API that requires an application id be included with every request. I'd like for this id to be accessible in every controller and I'd ideally like to only set it once. I can set it at the top level by doing:

```
angular.module('applicationName', 
['controller1', 'controller2', 'controller3'])
.constant('APPLICATION_ID', '12345abcde');
```

But I'd like to be able to access it in controller1/2/3. What's the best way to set the APPLICATION_ID variable so it's available in all components of the application?

Comment: Normally you would just inject it into the controller?!

Comment: I'd rather not have to inject a 64 character api key into every controller (there will be many more than three). I was hoping there's a more DRY way to do it.

Comment: Why exactly do you need it in every controller? For logging? Then decorate the $log service. To include in every HTTP request made by the application? Then modify the defaults of the $http service. If you need it in every controller then injection into each controller is the right answer. If you need it for other reasons then there are other answers.

Comment: @JohnBledsoe It's for making API calls, so modifying $http defaults might be a better option. Resources that discuss the topic would be most appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http - See the "Setting HTTP Headers" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      angular.module('applicationName', 
         ['controller1', 'controller2', 'controller3'])
         .constant('APPLICATION_ID', '12345abcde');
```

And then in your controller

```
      application.controller('myController', 
                        ['$scope','APPLICATION_ID',function($scope,applicationId)               
      {

         console.log("app id="+applicationId);

      }]);
```

Comment: How do I do this when I need to pass in $scope? I'm getting "Can't assign to read only attribute" errors on all properties of $scope when I try function($scope, applicationId)

Comment: I updated the example answer. You just pass in $scope and anything else you want as I've shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to send the `Application_ID` with every request to your api, as mentioned in the comments, you can modify the `$http` service to add the ID.

Define the constant

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .constant('APPLICATION_ID', 'foobarbaz');
```

Inject the constant into your `$http` service to send with every request.

```
angular
  .module('myModule')
  .config(httpConfig);

httpConfig.$inject = ['$httpProvider', '$provide'];

function httpConfig($httpProvider, $provide) {
  $provide.factory('httpInterceptor', ['APPLICATION_ID', function (APPLICATION_ID) {
    return {
      request: function (config) {
        // APPLICATION_ID can now be used in all your requests
        // Example:
        // To URL: GET /api/v1/users?appid=foobarbaz
        if (config.mehtod === 'GET') {
          var sep = config.url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
          config.url = config.url + sep + 'appid=' + APPLICATION_ID;
        }

        return config;
      }
    };
  }]);
}

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
```

Now you can use the `Application_ID` in all of your requests without the need to inject it into all of your controllers.

---

**Resources**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

- See section 'Setting HTTP Headers' on how to modify the headers sent
- See section 'Interceptors' for a more detailed example than the one above